# Angular - Auth0

Tags: angular, auth0

I am trying to add Auth0 to my angular app.

First, I followed https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular/01-login, but after login, Auth0 redirects me back to my callback page and it's work fine.

our problem is AuthO token automatically refreshes when the token expired.

How to stop the AuthO token from automatically refreshing?
We need to navigate to the login page after the token expired.

```
AuthModule.forRoot({
      "clientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "domain": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "cacheLocation": "localstorage",
        "useRefreshTokens": false,
        "useRefreshTokensFallback": false
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check the `httpInterceptor` and remove the call to refresh token if they have made from there

you can check the error handling in `httpInteceptor` where 401 will be checked and refresh token may be called